# JPA Many To Many Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

I have this classes:

**ChatRoom class:**

```
@Entity
public class ChatRoom {

    @Column(name="chatroom_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long chatroomId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="CHATROOM_USER",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="chatroom_id",referencedColumnName="chatroom_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="user_id")}
    )
    private Set<User> users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="chatroom", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<ChatRoomMessage> messages;
}
```

**User class:**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id", length=40, unique=true, updatable=false)
    private String  userId;
}
```

**ChatRoomMessage class:**

```
@Entity
public class ChatRoomMessage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long messageId;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="session_id", nullable=false)
    private User sender;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="chatroom_id", nullable=true)
    private ChatRoom chatroom;
}
```

If I want all messages that were sent by an user i made this at DAO:

**MessagesDAO class:**

```
@Repository
public class MessageDaoImpl implements MessageDaoI {
    @Override
    public List<ChatRoomMessage> getMessages(User u){
        Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ChatRoomMessage.class, "cmessage");
        c.createAlias("cmessage.sender", "sender");
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("sender", u));
        return c.list();
    }
}
```

The problem begins when I try to code the next queries:

1. Get all chatroom messages sent or received by a user.
2. Get all chatroom messages sent or received by a user on a chatroom.

Can you please give ideas on how to solve the queries?.

Comment: _"The problem begins ..."_ Which problem?

Comment: The problem I mean was to structure the criteria for the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as below:

First Query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from ChatRoomMessage as c JOIN c.sender where c.sender.userId = :senderUserId");
query.setString("senderUserId", "SENDER_USER_ID_TO_BE_SEARCHED");
List list = query.list();
```

Second Query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from ChatRoomMessage as c JOIN fetch c.chatroom where c.chatroom.users.userId = :senderUserId");
query.setString("senderUserId", "SENDER_USER_ID_TO_BE_SEARCHED");
List list = query.list();
```

Hope this solves you issue.

Comment: Hello, those queries would work if they only consider the sender, but; they both need to consider if a ChatroomMessage is **sent** or **received** by a user.

Comment: Which property maintain if message is received or sent??

Comment: a chatroommessage is sent by a user (the property "sender" on the chatroommessage class) and is send to a chatroom (the property "chatroom" on the chatrooommessage class), chatroom class contains the user set (many to many relationshipt) all the users in the chatroom must recieve the message (chatroommessage)